# log4net: Assembly System.Xml.XmlElement not referenced error, although not used

Tags: c#, .net, compiler-errors, log4net

I'm getting a weird compiler error when using log4net:

```
XmlConfigurator.Configure(new FileInfo("LogConfig.log4net")); // produces error
ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger("MyLogger");
log.Info("hello");
```

reports

*Error  1   The type 'System.Xml.XmlElement' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Xml, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.*

This happens on the first line, although I do not really mention any System.Xml things there myself. Also, it is probably noteworthy that I target .net 4.0 and the compiler demands the .net 2.0 assembly. I just recently switched my project to target 4.0.

Any suggestions? 
Thanks!

Comment: HAve you added reference to the `System.Xml.dll`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect the problem is that you're calling a method with *an overload* using a parameter of type `XmlElement`. While I can see the argument for it *not* failing, I think it's not entirely unreasonable to require the reference.

The simplest fix is just to add a reference to System.Xml.dll - it doesn't *really* need the .NET 2.0 version; it's just that that's the one that the log4net assembly references.

Comment: it worked..! with .net 4.0, even though it asked for the strong-named 2.0 version.. I can see that log4net has a point asking for System.Xml, but I actually gave the compiler the reference by adding 'using System.Xml' to no avail. Also, from my understanding, this reference should normally only be looked up at runtime. Weird.. anyway, thanks a lot!

Comment: @Efrain: Adding `using System.Xml;` doesn't give the compiler a reference to an *assembly* - it adds an import for a *namespace*. There's a very big difference between the two, and you need to understand that. The using directive *just* means that you can refer to types within that namespace by their simple name, and use extension methods declared within methods in that namespace. It doesn't do *anything* to the list of assemblies which are referenced by your assembly.

Comment: Well.. I am aware of that, but you cann not import a namespace without having the reference first. Or, this will produce the "are you missing a directive or assembly reference?" error message at this line. So, since adding "using System.Xml" at the top worked without errors, I assumed that the reference is present. Through some .net/VS magic - i.e. normally, you don't need to add .net references manually afaik.

Comment: @Efrain: That just means that *some* assembly is contributing a type to the `System.Xml` namespace. It may not be the same assembly. However, your previous comment of "I actually gave the compiler the reference by adding 'using System.Xml' to no avail" suggested that you thought that adding a using directive actually added an assembly reference, which it doesn't.